# Different ways to store web data Locally

Tags: javascript, database, local-storage

Is there anyway to have a client side small database that syncs with server side database whenever there is a change in data?

So I am looking at writing a javascript program to store a bunch of student application forms. But the internet connection is gonna be unstable as the personnel using it will be moving around campus to collect form data on his tablet.

I have looked at localstorage, but it does not have any database features.

I am really looking for technologies that can do local database entries and make asynchronous syncing easy (like what dropBox did was awesome except that it is not a web application)

I hope my question is clear 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "localstorage does not have any database features?" You're not going to find an in-browser SQL option any time soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon what kind of support you want.

Check out http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html#future where they talk about the Web SQL Database specification and IndexedDB.

It may work (Web SQL Database that is), since it sounds like a controlled environment.

Comment: Whew, perfect timing on my part ;) Any reason IndexedDB, based on current support?

Comment: Apple is about the only one that really wants to support WebSQL, while Microsoft and Google are both looking at IndexedDB. When it comes down to the two technologies, WebSQL is too open ended. They'll need to standardize on a database, and a derivative of SQL for Microsoft to ignore and implement their own version. With IndexedDB, it's more like a tree than a DB... And you can use many different methods to query it.

Answer (score 2):

following storage mechanisms when available:

- Standard HTTP Cookies
- Local Shared Objects (Flash Cookies)
- Silverlight Isolated Storage
- Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached 
   PNGs using HTML5 Canvas tag to read pixels (cookies) back out
- Storing cookies in HTTP ETags
- Storing cookies in Web cache
- Internet Explorer userData storage
- HTML5 Session Storage
- HTML5 Local Storage
- HTML5 Global Storage
- HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite

Copypasta from [evercookie description](http://samy.pl/evercookie/). Several items were removed because too short lifespan and/or too few space. Do not borrow his code, tho, it uses jquery and is clumsy in the other ways.